# OWIN / IdentityServer login stuck in endless loop

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, identityserver2

I have a working IdentityServer2 auth server that works fine.  I am creating a new .NET MVC application and following this article (http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/20/ws-federation-in-microsoft-owin-componentsa-quick-start/) to set up MS OWIN with IDS2.  I can reach the login screen but after logging in, the user is sent back to the calling website and gets stuck in an endless loop.

Startup.Auth.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation;
using Owin;

namespace AZBarMail
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType =
                       WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
                });
            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    MetadataAddress = "https://auth.azbar.org/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
                    Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44310/",
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Portion of web.config

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
</system.web>
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AZBarMail.Startup))]
namespace AZBarMail
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Redirect URL in IDS2

```
https://localhost:44310/
```

Comment: For my case, it turns out that I already got another account signed in from other web application. Found it out when everything works just fine in incognito browser mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue finally resolved.  Seems to have been an issue with the cookie type/settings.

Comment: Any chance you remember what exactly you did here? I'm facing the same issue at the moment.

Comment: @Drew, I had this <httpCookies requireSSL="true" domain=".xxx.net" /> where cookies/authtoken was only being sent to xxx.net domain.  anyone out site this domain weren't getting the token so these users were stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your user to /account/login.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/account/Login"),
                CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "SampleClient",
                ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter,
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/Logout")
            });

app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

From /account/login, redirect to the external provider.

The externalprovider will create a cookie on its domain and you will create a cookie on your domain after receiving the response from external provider.

Comment: But what if I don't have anything in my site called /account/Login?  I removed all the login pages from the project since the login is all handled on the SSO site.  Can I not redirect from the home page back to my home page?

Comment: SSO creates one cookie on its domain and another your site's domain, so SSO page needs to be told a redirect_uri, so that the SSO can redirect back to your page and you can create a cookie at your domain.